# Cast class factor into numeric

Tags: r, classification, knn

I'm trying to apply the knn algorithm into Smarket dataset (from the ISLR library) in order to classify the Direction class ( Up or Down ) based on the rest of numeric columns (Year, Lags, Today, Volume).

Doing the following:

```
aux2p1 <- knn(train=train[,1:8], test=test[,1:8], cl=train$Direction, k=1)
answer2 <- predict(aux2p1,testF)
```

But `validation$direction` contains strings. I'd like to cast it into numeric so Up will be 1 and Down will be 0 or something similar to avoid the error in arg(6) `as.factor("up/down")` which is inside the knn implementation.

However, the predict function will fail because it returns a factor with 2 levels and it does not work. Please help.